# Why isn't ScoreA and ScoreB adding egal?

Tags: python

This program is a simple rock paper scizzors program, but i cant seem to add the extra points to the score once there is a draw

```
from random import randint

def chifoumi():

  ScoreA = 0

  ScoreB = 0

  for i in range (1,50+1):
      egal = 0
      a = randint(1,3)
      b = randint(1,3)
      resultat = a - b
      
      while a == b:
        egal = egal + 1
        a = randint(1,3)
        b = randint(1,3)
      
      if resultat == 1:
        ScoreA=ScoreA + 1 * egal

      if resultat == -2:
        ScoreA=ScoreA + 1 * egal

      if resultat == -1:
        ScoreB=ScoreB + 1 * egal

      if resultat == 2:
        ScoreB=ScoreB + 1 * egal

      print("partie",i,"    ",ScoreA,"-",ScoreB,"      ",egal,"égalité(s)")

chifoumi()
```

The names are in french btw

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: `resultat` uses the values of `a` and `b` from before the `while` loop. You should set it after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update ScoreA or ScoreB when egal is not zero in each party,
you need to update resultat somewhere after a and b are updated in the while loop. for example,

```
  while a == b:
    egal = egal + 1
    a = randint(1,3)
    b = randint(1,3)
  # update resultat
  resultat = a - b
```